# Partly empty spaces in output after using euclidean allocation

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, location-allocation, euclidean

I have a polygon area with three smaller polygons in it. I would like to use the euclidean allocation tool from ArcGIS Pro in order to extend the three smaller polygons up to the border of the enclosing polygon area.

First I have converted the inner laying polygons to raster with a cell size of 0.72 and the enclosing polygon area to a polyline feature.

The resulting polyline feature I have used as 'feature barrier data'.

The output cell size was set to 10E-03. Now I am wondering why there are partly empty spaces in the output raster? The tool finished without errors.

Does anyone have an explantion?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run the tool and create correct output as shown below:

[image]

The key differences are:

- Set the outer polygon to be a *mask* in the environment settings of the tool and **not** a barrier as you had done.
- Ensure the environment setting, *processing extent*,  was set to the extent of the outer polygon.